# Everit validator: JsonSchema property named "type"

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using [Everit](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema), I'm trying to come up with a json schema that validates

```
{
  "type": "my content type",
  "name": "content name"
}
```

My solution:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "model.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "type",
        "name"
    ]
}
```

This generates the error:
properties/type: expected type is one of JsonArray or String, found: JsonObject

This schema loads just fine:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "model.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "some-type": {       <<-- Only field name changed
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "some-type",
        "name"
    ]
}
```

But the 'type' field is a database field that I don't want to rename.
How can I define the json schema to work with the property named 'type'?

Is the 'type' property name directly under properties interpreted as a reserved keyword?

Thx,
Ronald

Comment: This is a bug in the validator implementation. I suggest you raise an issue with the library's author.

Answer (score 1):

According to another validator (https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) your schema is completely fine.

This might be a bug in the Everit validator, so you could consider looking into alternatives as well. Personally, I've liked [networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) so far but haven't tested with your particular example.

That being said, according to the Everit documentation when it determines the applicable Draft version, it looks for this:

```
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"
```

However in your example you use:

```
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
```

Might be worth trying again without the trailing fragment (`#`).

Comment: Thanks @Carsten for your confirmation. Checked with and without the '#' and that didn't seem to make the difference. I'll see if it's a bug/feature in Everit.